# Combine different kinds of plots

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

how can i combine thats plots:

```
p1 = ContourPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + 100*(z - 11)^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 
  11.3}]
p2 = Manipulate[
 VectorPlot3D[{0, 0, -b^3 (x^2 + y^2) Cos[b^2 (x^2 + y^2)]}, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 11.3}], {b, 0.01, 3}]
Show[p1,p2]
```

i tried the "Show" function.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your other question: [How to combine Graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224391/how-to-combine-graphics)

Comment: no its not beacuse Show doesnt work here

Comment: `Show` does work here. If you provide an example of how you used `Show`, then we can tell you what’s wrong. (A likely mistake is that you are putting `Manipulate`, which is not a type of graphics, inside `Show`, rather than `Show` inside `Manipulate`.)

Comment: i update my code. if i cant use Manipulate inside Show how can i still controll the parmeter b

Comment: As @C.E. said, the `Show` needs to be inside the `Manipulate`. `Manipulate[Show[VectorPlot3D[...], p1], {b, 0.01, 3}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

cp3d = ContourPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + 100*(z - 11)^2 == 1,
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 11.3}];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  cp3d,
  VectorPlot3D[
   {0, 0, -b^3 (x^2 + y^2) Cos[b^2 (x^2 + y^2)]},
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 11.3},
   PlotLegends -> Automatic,
   VectorPoints -> vp]],
 {{vp, 4, VectorPoints}, Range[2, 6]},
 {{b, 1}, 0.01, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  Using a point pattern of "Mesh" gives much smaller arrows.

```
cp3d = ContourPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + 100*(z - 11)^2 == 1,
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 11.3},
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange,
     Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]]];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  cp3d,
  VectorPlot3D[
   {0, 0, -b^3 (x^2 + y^2) Cos[b^2 (x^2 + y^2)]},
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 11.3},
   VectorPoints -> {ppat, vp},
   VectorAspectRatio -> var]],
 {{ppat, "Mesh", "Point Pattern"}, 
   {"Hexagonal", "FaceCenteredCubic", "Mesh", "Regular"}},
 {{vp, 2, VectorPoints}, Range[2, 6],
  ControlType -> SetterBar},
 {{var, 1.5, VectorAspectRatio}, 0.1, 2, 0.05,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 1}, 0.01, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to scale the vectors down in the z direction? I can't figure it out for the life of me. I've tried VectorScaling / VectorSizes to no avail.

Comment: @flinty its an argument within [Arrow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html#182972311). I think that link should clarify it.

Comment: the code which was editted Fails to work.

Comment: i mean VectorAspectRatio is not working with VectorPlot3D

Comment: @amit - the documentation indicates that `VectorAspectRatio` is new in v12.1. Presumably, you have an earlier version. Just delete that option and the corresponding control.